why does the 'if' block also trigger after the 'else' gets triggered?
I have the following code, I am trying to implement a "a tap and hold" feature, where if I tap a for less than 300 ms, its supposed to fire the if block or if I hold down a, the else block should fire:
a::
    KeyWait,a,t0.300
    if !ErrorLevel
        tooltip, a tapped
else
    tooltip, a held down
    return

While it works for the most part, it has one issue. when the else block is fired and I release a, it will also fire the if block. I have tried a ton of things to figure out why this is, including experimenting with prefixes like $a:: but the issue persists.
What could I be doing wrong?
I am merely trying to achieve a generic feature where I can carry out different actions depending on if a button was tapped or held down. I am not interested in "double taps" or "double tap and hold", nor in complicated libraries like Tap hold Manager. If someone knows of a better way to do this in simple AHK code, I would appreciate it.
